# TCP server ignores incoming SYN

Tags: linux

I have a tcp server running. A client connects to the server and send packet periodically. For TCP server, this incoming connections turns to be CONNECTED, and the server socket still listens for other connections.

Say this client suddenly get powered off, no FIN sent to server. When it powers up again, it still use the same port to connect, but server doesn't reply to SYNC request. It just ignores incoming request, since there exists a connection with this port.

How to let server close the old connection and accept new one?

My tcp server runs on Ubuntu 14.04, it's a Java program using ServerSocket.

Answer (score 1):

That's not correct, a server can accept multiple connections and will accept a new connection from a rebooted client as long as it's connecting from a different port (and that's usually the case). If your program is not accepting it it's because you haven't called accept() a second time. This probably means that your application is only handling one blocking operation per time (for example, it might be stuck in a read() operation on the connected socket). The solution for this is to simultaneously read from the connected sockets and accept new connections. This might be done using an I/O multiplexer, like select(), or multiple threads.

Comment: I call listen() in main thread, and let other threads handling incoming connection. The problem is here, I always use the same port in client. If use a different port, it's good and server works. For now a workaround is setting read timeout in server to detect client power off and close that socket.

Comment: I want to know if there is an option to let server automatically close old connection on receiving new SYN on the same port.

Comment: No, the server cannot be disturbed by a rogue SYN on the same port, because it would be vulnerable to connection disruptions by ill intended clients. You need the keep alive for that.